# Swift regex with escaped backslash not working

Tags: swift, regex

I'm trying to find all instances of a string that starts with whitespace. On https://www.regexpal.com/ I can get a successful test by using this regex `^\s*` with this string `version:`.

But in my swift code, it fails.

Here's the code I am using:

```
//arrAllMatches is an array of matches run from a previous regex
for thisMatch in arrAllMatches {
    let arrWSMatch = myAppManager.perfromRegEx("^\\s*", thisMatch)
    print(arrWSMatch)
}

...
//in appManager

func perfromRegEx(_ strRegEx:String, _ strToSearch:String) -> Array<String> {

        var arrStringResults = [String]()
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: strRegEx)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: strToSearch.utf16.count)
        let arrMatches =  regex.matches(in: strToSearch, options: [], range: range)

        let strToSearch = NSString(string: strToSearch)
        for match in arrMatches {
            let range = match.range
            arrStringResults.append(strToSearch.substring(with: range))
        }

        return arrStringResults
    }
```

I run an initial regex to get a bunch of items, the second one is to clean out items with leading white space, but the results of the second one are all empty.

```
[""]
[""]
["  "]
["  "]
["  "]
[""]
[""]
[""]
[""]
["  "]
["    "]
["      "]
["      "]
["      "]
["      "]
["        "]
["          "]
["          "]
["          "]
["          "]
["          "]
["        "]
["          "]
["          "]
["          "]
["          "]
["          "]
```

It appears it is just grabbing the number of spaces of each result, not returning only results with white space. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change the regex to `^\s` or `^\s+`. Your `*` quantifier matches 0 or more (hence why you're getting empty results). Removing the quantifier will match exactly once and changing it to `+` will allow it match one or more whitespace characters. It's unclear if you simply want to match those that have at least one whitespace character at the start of the string or if you want to match the whitespace characters at the start of the string if they're present; in any case, these patterns allow you to do each.

Comment: Don't I need \\ to escape \ in Swift?

Comment: You're explicitly extracting just the matching portion (the whitespace): `strToSearch.substring(with: range)`. Is that not what you mean to do?

Comment: @PruitIgoe yes. I'm giving you the raw pattern - escape it as needed.

Comment: <sheepishGrin>Not at first cause my brain is slow, but then I realized it was giving me the data I needed (I just need to skip these) and so anything returned with a string.count > 0 I need to ignore. I tripped into what I needed but I'll still take the win.</sheepishGrin>

Answer (score 0):

Two issues, both mentioned in the comments

1. `*` searches for zero or more, so if there is no space at the beginning it matches anyway. Replace it with `+` (one or more)
2. `substring(with: range)` returns the found match, you certainly want the opposite, the substring without the leading spaces

In Swift it's highly recommended to use the native conversion from `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` and vice versa

```
//arrAllMatches is an array of matches run from a previous regex
for thisMatch in arrAllMatches {
    let arrWSMatch = myAppManager.perfromRegEx("^\\s+", thisMatch)
    print(arrWSMatch)
}

...
//in appManager

func performRegEx(_ strRegEx: String, _ strToSearch: String) -> Array<String> {

    var arrStringResults = [String]()
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: strRegEx)
    let range = NSRange(strToSearch.startIndex..., in: strToSearch)
    let arrMatches =  regex.matches(in: strToSearch, range: range)

    for match in arrMatches {
        let range = Range(match.range, in: strToSearch)!
        arrStringResults.append(String(strToSearch[range.upperBound...]))
    }

    return arrStringResults
}
```

I would also highly recommend to make the function `throw` and catch a possible pattern syntax error.